# Want to get current date in mysql in required format

Tags: mysql

I want to get Current date in my sql like **130615** format for example , current date is 2013-06-15 so i need to get date as 130615. how it can be done?

Comment: Google `mysql format date`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING('your_date_column', 3), '-', '') from ....
```

here a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfe05/4)

Comment: Not only would it be better in principle to use actual date formatting functions, but this would give 20130615 instead of 130615.

Comment: edlited my answwer hope this you look for

Comment: It's still unnecessarily convoluted, but I suppose it's not completely wrong anymore.

Comment: added a demo to answer